# Is there a general integration formula for an integrated of a quadruple of polynomials?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was looking for a formula to integrate the following $$ \int (A+Bx)^l(a+bx)^m(c+dx)^n(e+fx)^p dx$$ where $\{m,n,p,q\} \in \mathbb{R}$, I tried to find it in "Gradshteyn and Ryzhik,Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" but I could not find it there. I found a solution to a similar form in wekipedia [List of integrals of rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions)
, $$ \int (A+Bx)(a+bx)^m(c+dx)^n(e+fx)^p dx=\frac{(Ab-aB)(a+bx)^{m+1}(c+dx)^n(e+fx)^{p+1}}{b(m+1)(af-be)}+\frac{1}{b(m+1)(af-be)}$$ which is represents $l=1$, I'm interested in case when $A=0$ and $l\ne1$.

Comment: In general? No, not unless you'd accept an answer in terms of multivariate hypergeometric functions with obscure names. There's some info here that might help you: https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16#ii